# Making bank account

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a bank account using Ruby. I'm getting a undefined method or local variable error even though the method is already defined, could someone tell me what's wrong with this code? I have tried rewriting the main_menu method but am still getting the same error.

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :checking_account, :savings_account

  def initialize(name, checking_account, savings_account)
    @name = name
    @checking_account = checking_account
    @savings_account = savings_account
  end
end

def display
  puts "Enter your PIN:"
  input = gets.chomp

  if input = pin
    main_menu
  else
    bad_pin
  end
end

def main_menu
  puts """
    Welcome back #{name}!
    Would you like to:
    Display Balance press '1'
    Make Withdrawl press '2'
    Make Deposit press '3'
    Exit press '4'
  """

  input = gets.chomp

  case option
    when 1
      balance
    when 2
      withdrawl
    when 3
      deposit
    else
      exit
  end
end

def balance
  puts "Which balance? Checking or Savings?"
  input = gets.chomp

  if input =~ /checking/i
    puts "Your balance for your Checking Account is: $#{checking_account}."
  elsif input =~ /savings/i
    puts "Your balance for your Savings Account is: $#{savings_account}."
  else
    main_menu
  end
end

def withdrawl(pin_number, amount)
  puts "Enter PIN to make a withdrawl:"
  input = gets.chomp

  case withdrawl
    when checking_account
      @checking_account -= amount
      puts "You have withdrawn $#{amount}; you now have ${checking_account} in your checking."
    when savings_account
      @savings_account -= amount
      puts "You have withdrawn ${amount}; you now have $#{savings_account} in your savings."
    else
      bad_pin
  end
end

def deposit
  puts "Which account would you like to deposit into: Checkings, or Savings?"
  input = gets.chomp

  if input =~ /checking/i
    @checking_account += amount
    puts "You have made a deposit of $#{amount} leaving you with $#{checking_account}."
  elsif input =~ /savings/i
    @savings_account += amount
    puts "You have made a deposit of $#{amount} leaving you with $#{savings_account}."
  else
    main_menu
  end
end

def pin
  @pin = 1234
end

def bad_pin
  puts "Access Denied: incorrect PIN"
  exit
end

my_account = Account.new("Thomas", 500_000, 750_000)
display
```

The error I'm recieving is this:

```
bank.rb:25:in `main_menu': undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object (NameError)
        from bank.rb:16:in `display'
        from bank.rb:101:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: I'm using geddit, and it doesn't indent for you.

Comment: `if input = pin`: comparing for equality is done with `==`. `=` is for assignments. `"""` is also wrong. A single quotation mark (`"`) is enough.

Comment: AWH! Cool thanks man!

Comment: Wouldn't I have to use commas if I used a single quotation? 

    IE: `puts "HI",`
               `"Hello"`

Comment: @Ekult3k: If you have no tool doing the indentation for you, you will have to do it all by yourself. Your code is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all methods inside class

And call your display method on instance of class i.e. in your case my_account

This should do the trick! :)

Comment: just upvote and accept the answer if you dont mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put all those methods into the `Account` class body. Otherwise they will not see the instance variables or `attr_reader` methods.

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :checking_account, :savings_account

  def initialize(name, checking_account, savings_account)
    @name = name
    @checking_account = checking_account
    @savings_account = savings_account
  end
end   # <---- This closes your class, it has to be moved past the last method
```

This error is immediately visible with proper indentation.

And at the end, you call `display` of `my_account`:

```
my_account.display
```

Comment: It seems he *wants* those methods to be outside the class. I.e. he's just calling `display` at the end.

Comment: I think that's another mistake caused by first one. He is accessing instance variables all the way.

Comment: Sorry got busy, I see what you're talking about and I fixed it, thanks for the help.